# Call Service on change of Route in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new in angular2 and creating aproject usibg angularjs.In my application i want to call the service when user changes route with params. When i come first time then service calls succesfully but when i change paramteres than my service is not calling. here is my code:

```
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,
private service: CourseService

){}
    private player: Player;
    id:'';
    coursesData:'';
    courseDetail:'';
  getModulesData:'';


    ngOnInit() {
     this.route.params.subscribe(params =>
       this.id = params["id"]
    )
    var courseList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("courses"));
    this.coursesData = courseList.data;
    for(var i=0; i<courseList.data.length; i++){
        if(courseList.data[i].course_id == 4){
            this.courseDetail = courseList.data[i]
            break;
        }
    }
    this.service.getCourseDetails(this.id).subscribe((courseDetails:any) =>{

        this.getModulesData = courseDetails.data
    })
    setTimeout(function(){
   this.player = new Player("player");
     }, 0);
  }


}
```

Comment: In your subscription you only set the new id. you have to call the service in the subscription, too

Answer (score 0):

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params =>
    this.id = params["id"]

    var courseList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("courses"));
    this.coursesData = courseList.data;
    for(var i=0; i<courseList.data.length; i++){
        if(courseList.data[i].course_id == 4){
            this.courseDetail = courseList.data[i]
            break;
        }
    }
  this.service.getCourseDetails(this.id).subscribe((courseDetails:any) =>{
    this.getModulesData = courseDetails.data
   })
    setTimeout(function(){
       this.player = new Player("player");
    }, 0);
  )
}
```